# Custom iOS keyboard accesses container without Full Access privileges

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios-app-extension, ios-keyboard-extension

**Summary**

I'm currently implementing a custom iOS keyboard. I need to share data between the keyboard and the containing apps. This works to some extent even if the user has disabled full access. Why?

**The Details**

To share data between the keyboard and the containing app, I have installed an app group and use

```
NSFileManager
    .defaultManager()
    .containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("mySuiteName")
```

to share files and

```
NSUserDefaults(suiteName:"mySuiteName")
```

for other settings.

As far as I understand, the user has to activate full access for my keyboard in the system settings. The [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW1) states:

> If you request open access by setting this key’s value to YES, your keyboard gains the following capabilities [...]:
>
> - Option to use a shared container with the keyboard’s containing app, which enables features such as providing a custom lexicon management UI in the containing app

I have added the required property to the plist file and see the according option in the keyboard settings. To test if the user has allowed full access to the keyboard I went with the known approach and test for pasteboard availability

```
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().isKindOfClass(UIPasteboard)
```

which works as expected.

However, I noticed that if full access is **disabled** I can still load images **from the keyboard** using

```
UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
```

with `imagePath` pointing to a file in the shared container. I have tested this on two devices running iOS 9.2. Shouldn't this be impossible? I'm wondering if I misunderstood the restrictions to the shared container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point between iOS 8.0 and 9.0 (I want to say 8.3, but I can't remember the exact version) Apple changed the restrictions on custom keyboards so that they had *read-only* access to the shared container -- both the file system and the `NSUserDefaults` associated with it, even when full access is disabled.

The documentation hasn't been updated yet. You should file a radar.